# Move semantics in a game of solitaire

Tags: c++

I'm writing a solitaire backend in `C++`. Life is easier if I didn't have to wonder whether something is being copied or moved, but what's the point of `C++` in that case? I'd just use Python :D.

Anyhoo - I have a Card object which observes the rule of 5 (It has a Constructor, Copy Constructor, Copy Assignment Operator, Move Constructor, Move Assignment Operator). I have separate classes for the various stacks of cards.

So far, I've been using a `std::vector<Card> cards` to store the cards and every time I need to move a card from one stack to another, I do:

```
auto last_card = cards.back(); // Get the last element in the collection.
cards.pop_back(); // Remove the last element.
return std::move(last_card); // Move the card and return it.
```

My question is - Is this the right way to do this? Should I instead have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>` instead so that all I'm ever doing is copying/moving pointers around and not the real objects?

I'm looking for best practices as I'm still new to C++. Any tips/advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, `Card` object is quite simple really. Just a suit, value and color (inferred by suit). All 3 are enums and there are additional helper functions for flipping the card, checking if it's face up or down etc.

Comment: Can you tell me please why you use `move` instead of just returning `last_card`? Some C++ best practice I don't know about?

Comment: Without seeing what's in your `Card` class it's impossible to say. But my (superficial) reaction is that this is far too complicated; a card is just a couple of values (suit and rank), and the default versions of the special functions will work just fine. There's no need to worry about moving versus copying -- they're the same.

Comment: Returning by move is often a mistake. It can inhibit copy elision (which is better than move).

Comment: Does `Card` wrap any resource (e.g., memory)?

Comment: `return last_card;` is a better solution. Local variables with automatic storage duration are treated as rvalues in `return` statements. You also likely want `auto last_card = std::move(cards.back());`, otherwise you copy the last element, which is then immediately destroyed.

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify what `Card` contains. It's a very simple object. From what everyone here is saying, I'm overthinking it? Maybe I should completely ignore the move semantics and just let the compiler handle the copying/moving optimisation?

Comment: @PlastyGrove Yes, if the `Card` class has just 3 member variables and all are enums, you will be perfectly fine with compiler-generated copy/move constructors. Simply do not user-define them, or define them as defaulted (by `= default`).

Comment: @DanielLangr - I see. That makes sense. So if the object in question is not overly complicated and copying isn't expensive then I should just keep it simple.

Comment: @DanielLangr Please use the answer section thanks

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You did it for me already, thanks :). I think you answer is now complete.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty much fine, except for a couple of details:

```
return std::move(last_card); // Move the card and return it.
```

It's a common misconception that you need to, or should, do this. In a `return` statement, the thing on the right is automatically an *xvalue* so it is in a moveable condition already. In that sense, `std::move` is redundant there.

But it's a little worse than that because by writing `std::move` you're making it harder for the compiler to completely elide even the move — by just writing `return last_card` you will either get the move you wanted in the first place, or even better a total return-value elision that avoids the whole shebang.

Now, currently you have a copy coming out of `cards.back()`; the `cards.back()` expression isn't an rvalue there because it's a reference to something that exists elsewhere, which is basically an lvalue! So you might like to do:

```
auto last_card = std::move(cards.back());
```

Also I just want to caution you against the "move the card and return it" observation: remember, `std::move` doesn't move anything, it just gives you an rvalue expression referring to a thing. If a move occurs, it'll be *within* the return operation, not before it.

In conclusion, my suggestion:

```
// Extract the last element in the collection
auto last_card = std::move(cards.back());

// Remove the now-dead last element
cards.pop_back();

// Return the new card (will automatically be moved if elision doesn't occur)
return last_card;
```

But, this is all kind of moot based on your description of `Card`, which is very simple and doesn't get any benefit from a move. Frankly you could just copy it around and get the same results. Still, it's nice to be prepared for it to become more complex in the future. Certainly there's nothing here that screams for a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Stealing YSC's testcase, this produces [just one move](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f27cb92b041023f) and nothing else (ignoring the setup)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! So in my case for an ultra simple `Card` object, I can get away even with `auto last_card = cards.back();`?

Comment: @PlastyGrove Sure. You have no indirect resources so there's nothing to "move". You're going to be copying those enums no matter what.